# How to access local IP based camera stream over the internet?

Tags: video-streaming

I have a Linux computer(with camera) running ROS based web-video-server (http://wiki.ros.org/web_video_server) and live stream from camera can be accessed by any computer via web browser over the local network. Now I want this video to broadcast over the internet for some specific remote user so that he can access the live stream on his browser, What is the best way of achieving this?

Comment: Add a port-forwarding rule on your firewall and setup that port in the DMZ, then hope your ISP doesn't change your IP address or setup a DynDNS account to handle that potential issue.   Not knowing what your home network looks like and what sort of router/firewall you have, I'm not sure how detailed a reply you'll get.  Oh.. and some ISPs intentionall block outbound streaming and certain ports to..  be prepared to deal with that too.  Good luck.

Comment: Thank you, other than port forwarding is there any way to host a video streaming server? may be I can look for other reliable method

Comment: There may be other options; it all depends on your hardware and what sort of traffic shaping your ISP might do.  Some block upstream services, in which case you'd need to do something really fancy like setup a VPN to tunnel the traffic through an external proxy (you'd connect to that external proxy) or a similar solution with ssh tunneling.